# Windows phone 7 - how to connect to remote services

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7-emulator

I want to connect to remote machine using windows phone 7.5. Is there any inbuilt classes in .net for this.

For regular desktop application same can be done using ServiceController class. I am looking for the similar class for windows phone application.

Answer (score 1):

ServiceController is used to control state of services on local or remote machine.

WP apps don't have a way of controlling remote or local services.

You would have to write SOAP or REST API for managing services and then connect WP app to those, but do make sure it is secured properly - you don't want to give access to service control to everyone.